# GPL licensing a web app software

Tags: licensing, gpl

I am in the early stages of building a software with a team to design websites, kind of like WordPress. You download the system on your website, and go on from there. People can be allowed to expand the system.

I don't know much about licensing and copyright, so about the GPL license, I just state the authors and put the license text in the software release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For web applications, you might want to consider using the [AGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html) instead of the GPL.)

Assuming that the whole software was created by your team, you should follow these steps to license the software under the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html):

- Add a **copyright notice** to each source file.
- Add a **copying permission statement** to each source file.
- Add the **full license** as [plain text file](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt) to your project.

For details, read [*How to use GNU licenses for your own software*](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html).

On top of that, you might want to state that the software is licensed under the GPL in other places, too:

- Mention it in the **user interface** of the software. For example, under "Help → About" or in similar places. It’s likely that not all users read the source files, and sometimes users end up using your software without having installed it themselves – these people might not be aware that it’s free software.
- Mention it on your **website**. Ideally on your homepage, as feature, next to the download link etc. It can be a big advantage, and many people won’t even consider using software unless it’s free/libre.
- (Many web applications that create websites also include the software name/link and the license information in the **footer** of the created websites, acting as some kind of advertisement. But it might be nicer to make this opt-in instead of opt-out.)